# Using filter(chunk) gives error

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I am using Laravel-Excel 2.1. I am trying to use chunk() to read a large imported Excel file but I got the error "Method noHeading does not exist."

**My original code**

This code works fine reading the imported files.

```
$column_number = 5;
$rows = Excel::load('storage/app/public/upload/myfiles.xlsx', function($reader) use ($column_number)
{
    $reader->noHeading();
    $reader->takeColumns($column_number);
    $reader->setDateFormat('d-m-Y');

})->get();
```

**After using chunks as in documentation**

This code gives `Method noHeading does not exist.` error. Notice I added `filter('chunk')` and `chunk(250`

```
$column_number = 5;
$rows = Excel::filter('chunk')->load('storage/app/public/upload/myfiles.xlsx')->chunk(250, function($reader) use ($column_number)
{
    $reader->noHeading();
    $reader->takeColumns($column_number);
    $reader->setDateFormat('d-m-Y');

})->get();
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but: if you use `chunk`, it's maybe because you have high memory consumption. There are also some memory friendly alternatives to Laravel Excel such as https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel

Comment: I might test this package, but its seems like lack several functions like `noHeading(), takeColumns(), etc` or im wrong

Answer (score 0):

The `$reader` variable passed to your closure is an instance of `ExcelParser`, not `LaravelExcelReader` so doesn't have the `noHeading()` method. `Excel::filter()` does return a reader, so you should be able to do this:

```
$column_number = 5;
$rows = Excel::filter('chunk')
    ->noHeading()
    ->takeColumns($column_number)
    ->setDateFormat('d-m-Y');
    ->load('storage/app/public/upload/myfiles.xlsx')
    ->chunk(250, function($results) {return $results;});
```

Totally untested though!

Comment: oh no wonder...but i got an error `Type error: Too few arguments to function Maatwebsite\Excel\Readers\LaravelExcelReader::chunk(), 1 passed in ` ...  `and at least 2 expected`

Comment: Sorry, just put an empty function in there. Copy/paste error.

Comment: now i got another error `Call to a member function get() on null`, when i remove the `get()`, it returns null...clearly it has contents

Comment: Ok, not sure then. It's been quite a while since I used this package and I never used the `chunk()` feature of it. It's poorly documented and counter-intuitive, which is probably why I stopped using it! I did one more edit, you can see what happens with it...

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to update your code like below,

```
$column_number = 5;
$rows = Excel::filter('chunk')->load('storage/app/public/upload/myfiles.xlsx')->chunk(250, function($data) use ($column_number)
 {
     foreach($data as $reader){
       $reader->noHeading();
       $reader->takeColumns($column_number);
       $reader->setDateFormat('d-m-Y');
     }
 })->get();
```

Comment: i just tried the code, but it still display the same error